# Mapbox turn by turn navigation - custom notification -- battery consumption is high

Tags: android, mapbox

I am working on a requirement to provide turn by turn navigation in one of our application. I am able to to build the app and works well. I have added custom notification feature to custom navigation activity, the notification works well but my device battery consumption is very high and some times I am getting warning this application is consuming more battery message.

Can any one help me on this point. I need to save the battery utilisation as well.

Here is my code snippet.

public class CustomNavigationNotification implements NavigationNotification {

```
private static final int CUSTOM_NOTIFICATION_ID = 91234821;

private Notification customNotification;
private NotificationCompat.Builder customNotificationBuilder;
private NotificationManager notificationManager;
private int numberOfUpdates;

public CustomNavigationNotification(Context context) {
    // Get the notification manager to update your notification
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Store the builder to update later
    customNotificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, NAVIGATION_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.caramaps_g)
            .setContentTitle("App name")
            .setContentText("Happy journey");

    // Build the notification
    customNotification = customNotificationBuilder.build();
}

@Override
public Notification getNotification() {
    return customNotification;
}

@Override
public int getNotificationId() {
    return CUSTOM_NOTIFICATION_ID;
}

@Override
public void updateNotification(RouteProgress routeProgress) {
    // Update the builder with a new number of updates
    customNotificationBuilder.setContentText("Diatance you traveled : " + routeProgress.distanceTraveled());

    // Notify the notification manager
    notificationManager.notify(CUSTOM_NOTIFICATION_ID, customNotificationBuilder.build());
}
}
```

Here I am passing custom notification to my navigation options builder.

```
MapboxNavigationOptions options1 = MapboxNavigationOptions.builder()                              .navigationNotification(mCustomNavigationNotification)
                            .maneuverZoneRadius(70)
                            .build();
NavigationViewOptions options = NavigationViewOptions.builder()
                            .directionsRoute(currentRoute)
                            .directionsLanguage(Locale.getDefault())
                            .navigationOptions(options1)

.awsPoolId(null).shouldSimulateRoute(simulateRoute).build();
```

please  suggest me if I am going wrong path....

Thanks in advance....